# Typescript compiles not needed/required source

Tags: typescript

TS 2.6.2, there are three files in dir:

interface.ts:

```
export interface Env {
    x: string
}
```

index.ts:

```
import {Env} from './interface' // imports only interface

const env: Env = {x: '1'}

console.log(env.x)
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "include": [
    "index.ts"
  ]
}
```

I do compilation: `tsc --outDir ./out`, in out dir I see:

```
index.js
inteface.js
```

(If I remove `import {Env} from './interface'` from `index`, I will see only `index.js`)

I wonder why TSC is compiling in JS `interface.js` if `index.ts` imported only interface from `interface.ts` it not JS CODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. Here's a [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10908).

The files key in your config just shows Typescript the starting points. Since `index.ts` imports `interface.ts` the type checker has to parse `interface.ts` in order to check the types.

As for why an empty file is created, Ryan Cavanaugh answers that in the above GitHub issue:

> The problem is what happens when you go from a 1-statement file to a 0-statement file during separate compilations -- without emitting the blank file, you might still be loading and executing that 1 statement.